# Prevent xdg-open to open mistyped files as URLs

Tags: xdg-open

I am often inadvertently trying to open incomplete filenames with `xdg-open`, because of the presence of several files with the same basename but different extensions, e.g. `very-long-filename.tex`, `very-long-filename.pdf` etc. Using autocomplete in terminal gives me

```
xdg-open very-long-filename.
```

and I hit return before checking the name is complete. Instead of an error, this launches my web browser and attempts to open the URL `http://very-long-filename./`, which is a nuisance.

I never use `xdg-open` to open URLs from terminal. Is it possible to block xdg-open from opening URLs from terminal if they don't explicitly contain `http://` or `https://` (or at all), without compromising other URL-opening strategies used by the OS (Ubuntu/Kubuntu)?

I looked at `xdg-settings` and `xdg-mime` but the doc is not very exhaustive and it's not obvious to me that this can be achieved. It's not clear why `xdg-open` defaults to opening anything that is not a filename as a URL, and what kind of mime-type this is.

Comment: I might be spitballing here, but it sounds like it might be something in your `~/.config/mimeapps.list` that might be tied to not having an extension to default to web browser.  Maybe try renaming the file and try again.

Comment: ... or perhaps executing `xdg-mime query filetype very-long-filename.` would tell us something?

Comment: @Terrance: renaming `mimeapps.list` didn't help (it attempted to open as an URL in Chrome rather than in Firefox)... @steeldriver: the error message is `xdg-mime: file 'very-long-filename.' does not exist`. That's part of the problem, I don't see in mime anything that is not a file or not specific. E.g. I see `x-scheme-handler/http` which is handled by `firefox`, but why would this be followed without mentioning `http` in the argument of `xdg-open`?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the `xdg-open` possibly.  I guess you can try filing a bug against it by running `ubuntu-bug xdg-open` or maybe try reinstalling the `xdg-utils`; `sudo apt install --reinstall xdg-utils`

Comment: @Terrance I tried it on a Live Kubuntu 22.04 USB and the same behaviour occurs, so it's not due to an obscure configuration of mine. Same as well with `kde-open`.  Does it occur on a live Ubuntu too? Reinstalling `xdg-utils` doesn't help either. I'll file a bug at `xdg-utils`, though it might be a feature rather than a bug. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I guess it could be a feature of KDE then, but that is very strange.  I use Xubuntu 22.04 and it definitely gives me an error of unable to open whatever file I am trying when not specifying a file extension when it has one.